# Pyspark Dataframe: Transform many columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with 10 columns as read from a parquet file

```
df = spark.read.parquet(path)
```

I want to apply several pre-processing steps to a subset of this dataframe's columns: `col_list`.

The following works fine, but apart from a bit ugly, I also have the feeling it is not optimal.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

for col in col_list:
    df = df.withColumn(col, F.regexp_replace(col, ".", " ")
    df = df.withColumn(col, F.regexp_replace(col, "_[A-Z]_", "")
```

and the list goes on with other similar text processing steps.

So the question is whether the above is as optimal and elegant as it gets and also if/how I can use `transform` to achieve a sequential execution of the above steps.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all the required columns in one go:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select(
    *[c for c in df.columns if c not in col_list],
    *[F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(c, ".", " "), "_[A-Z]_", "").alias(c) for c in df.columns if c in col_list]
)
```